# Suspended for 1 year by bot

Tags: support

I asked this question [How to calculate the strength of fictional creatures when creating them or at least be precise and believable?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/238831/99903) and then the morning after found my account deleted.

Then I tried making another account to ask another question, this time it was instantly suspended, well... more like 15 seconds after posting the question, the question was closed and my account ''boom gone''

I haven't used this website in almost a year, well actually it is probably a year maybe slightly more, at least can you restore my old account? I don't remember the nickname but I wasn't ever banned on that account. The bot knows my old nickname so you moderators must know it too, I wasn't evading any ban as I'm almost certain I was not banned, but feel free to check.

Edit:

This is my first account:

Charon in 2016, haven't used it in 6 years, never banned, just forgot email and password, but I was a kid, the email was probably something edgy like baphometh...something...something@gmail.com

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/24960/charon

Then my account from 2021, the password is certainly the same as this one. I asked a question about a continent, one of the cities in the map had the name ''Velsia''

Comment: Interesting your question didn't get closed or vastly downvoted, these are usually the ban reasons, at least those easily recognized by AIs. What was the second question which was put out of service instantly? Was it closed (with an header [closed/duplicate]) or deleted (invisible and unreachable)?

Comment: @Tortliena it was [closed] but then soon became invisible, a matter of seconds.

Comment: It seems like OP has a legitimate complaint. Even if folks dislike that original "strength" question, it clearly doesn't warrant a ban. I, for one, would like to see whatever justification was used by this site or community for banning or deleting the original account. In the absence of a legitimate justification, I find OP's sockpuppet workaround justifiable.

Answer (score 1):

Though SE doesn't forbid having multiple accounts, creating multiple accounts with the scope of circumventing system or moderator imposed sanctions is not allowed and will inevitably result in the additional accounts being removed.

Comment: What'd be interesting to know is why the first account was banned, because it looks like the querent doesn't know nor doesn't know a way of knowing without creating a new one ^^. Then can you actually ease the tension and morally prevent the person from creating over and over to pledge for a reopening.

Comment: The deletion of his newest account was understandable: duplicate account, trying to get around a ban. But it's understandable that he thought the ban was some sort of mistake, as there was no apparent reason for it, so he just made a new one. That is still the question: what was the reason for his ban in the first place? Is there no record? Could some algorithm ban your account right now and we'd just all go "Oh well, we'll never know why L.Dutch got suspended for a year"?